# Move UV texture in screen space?

Tags: texturing, uv, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes, vector-mapping

I have a UV mapped texture. I want to be able to adjust its location with the mapping node (or other vector math.) in Screen space. If you put the UV vector through a mapping node and change the location, it will move in UV space. I want the location to change in Screen Space for whatever angle I'm currently looking at, like it would if I was using Camera or Window projection in the first place (but without the texture being constantly in Camera/Window space.)

Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible to convert world space to camera space, using math that can be done in shader nodes, given the FOV.  But it's tedious, and it doesn't give you anything different than window space (it's not the same as camera space unless the camera is orthogonal, in which case window and camera space are the same thing other than some translation.)  What is your end goal here?

Comment: I don't quite understand what the difference between view projection and what you want?

Comment: @Crantisz When you map with camera/view in the first place, then the initial placement of the texture is defined in that space. I want to define it with the UV map, and only use the camera/window as a small offset from that when moving the camera.

Comment: @Nathan I'm trying to do Partial Derivatives in screen space similar to dFdx. This does work fine in UV space, but then it doesn't handle surface curvature quite right.

Comment: I wish Blender did that, but it doesn't.  There are two tricks, but they're both hacky, irritating, and very limited.  One is to do a pre-render of UV so that you can get delta UV/delta screen pos.  The other is to parent a pair of empties to vertices with a known delta UV to measure the delta pos.

Comment: @nathan I'm interested in learning more about both of those. I'm deep into hacky stuff anyhow. Do you have any links? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, no links, just stuff I've come up with.  They're hacks in a bad way: they are really too limited and error-prone for most uses.

Comment: @Nathan Alright, fair enough.